# how to add a menu to the new icon in eclipse via plugin

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, rcp

I have a plugin project through which I want to add a new type of project. I was able to get it done through 'File -> New' option. But, I also want to include it in the menu of new icon button in Eclipse and also 'Right Click -> New' option

Answer (score 1):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.newWizards` extension point to add a New wizard to all these locations.

More details about this wizard [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fdialogs_wizards_newWizards.htm)